# Not able to spy Web objects in UFT 14

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am unable to spy on web object.
I have selected all plugins like web, visual basic etc. Its a demo version software. I am unable to spy any web element. Sometimes eg: it shows Gmail application objects as Win objects. please help

Comment: Have you opened the browser **after** opening UFT? [Is the `BHOManager Class` add-on enabled in the browser](http://bienabee.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/1000214134-hp-uft-error-the-uft-browser-helper-object-is-required-for-this-step-make-sure-the-bhomanager-clas)?

Comment: Yes opened browser after opening UFT.

Comment: How about the BHOManager add-on? Is it enabled? Did you try to enable only the Web add-in when opening UFT?

Comment: Have you seen [this website with 19 things to try when QTP/UFT does not recognize the objects?](http://www.learnqtp.com/uft-object-identification-tips/) If none of these help you put, I'd suggest you contact HP support

Comment: Which browser are you testing?

Comment: I am using firefox

Comment: What version of FF you are using?

Comment: FF Version 46.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the GUI scaling in the Windows settings to 100%. Then log-out and log back into windows.